# PiFace Digital 2 and Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python, pi-3, emulation, piface

I have a PiFace Digital 2 and a Pi i 3 with the latest Debian and Pixel installed. My first question is, is the PiFace digital 2 compatible with the Pi 3? From what I can tell they are.

Secondly, I can't seem to get the emulator to run. I have turned on SPI and installed, following instructions [here](https://github.com/piface/pifacedigital-emulator) when running a sample program I get the following:

```
python3 /usr/share/doc/python3-pifacedigitalio/examples/blink.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/doc/python3-pifacedigitalio/examples/blink.py", line 9, in <module>
    pifacedigital = pifacedigitalio.PiFaceDigital()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pifacedigitalio/core.py", line 82, in __init__
    self.init_board()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pifacedigitalio/core.py", line 107, in init_board
    h=self.hardware_addr, b=self.bus, c=self.chip_select))
pifacedigitalio.core.NoPiFaceDigitalDetectedError: No PiFace Digital board detected (hardware_addr=0, bus=0, chip_select=0).
```

Any ideas on how to get this working ?

Comment: I know this will be a late reply. But this resolved my issues. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=170606

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this will be a late reply. But this resolved my issues.

I had the same issue. It turns out (thanks to gam3t3ch ) that the later kernels for RPI3 uses an incompatible frequence for the SPI serial channel (basically it is higher than what PiFace Digital 2 can handle - lowering this makes the display work again,

Edit file 
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pifacecommon/spi.py

## create the spi transfer struct

```
    transfer = spi_ioc_transfer(
        tx_buf=ctypes.addressof(wbuffer),
        rx_buf=ctypes.addressof(rbuffer),
        len=ctypes.sizeof(wbuffer),
        speed_hz=ctypes.c_uint32(100000) 
    )
```

Note the added setting for the speed_hz field. 
For me this solves all problems I had with the board on newer kernels.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=170606